# Issues with custom navigation and displaying submenu on hover

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get this menu system to work for a good while now and am after looking at a number of different solutions but nothing seems to be working for me.

At the moment the submenu is appearing when hovering over the top level menu but if I try to move the mouse down to the submenu it disappears again as soon as my mouse leaves the top level.

Also when it does show it is showing behind some of the other page content, I think his might be because I have the page header which contains the navigation in a seperate include() file.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, my code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">category</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">category</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">category</a></li>
        </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
    <li>Hello,</li>
    <li><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">country</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">cart</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav{
    height:50px;
}
#nav > ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#nav > ul:nth-child(1){
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#nav > ul:nth-child(2){
    float:right;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
}
#nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#nav > ul:nth-child(1) > li{
    width:100px;
}
#nav > ul:nth-child(2) > li{
    padding-left:10px;
}
#nav > ul > li > ul{
    display:none;
}
#nav > ul > li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
    z-index:5;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width:200px;
}
#nav > ul > li:hover > ul > li{
    background: #fff;
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    line-height:16px;
    font-weight:normal;
}
#nav > ul > li:hover > ul > li > a{
    color:#333;
}
```

Comment: It is working for me, I've tried Firefox and Chrome, I can hover on "Menu" and go down to the "category". Checkout your browser cache

Comment: yeah I was sure I had everything fine and it should have been working it must be with how I have the pages set up. I'm using php to generate all the html. I'm using <?php include_once("page_header.php"); ?> to include the page header of which the nav div is the last element so when moving the mouse down you're moving out of that section and my menu is actually <li><a href="#">Menu</a><ul><?php echo $category_menu; ?></ul></li>

Comment: I don't think this should make much of a difference though

Comment: i thought that the fact that it is appearing behind other elements on the page when it is showing might mean that my mouse is actually on those elements rather than still on the actual menu but that should be appearing at the front with z-index set to 5

Comment: yeah so it works fine when there's nothing below that element but if there's something below it, it goes behind that element, I've tried changing the z-index but it still appears behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost done, you need to set a `z-index`, and `position: relative`. This is because `z-index` needs to be set with a position (more information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)).

```css
#nav{
    height:50px;
}
#nav > ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#nav > ul:nth-child(1){
    float:left;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#nav > ul:nth-child(2){
    float:right;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
}
#nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#nav > ul:nth-child(1) > li{
    width:100px;
}
#nav > ul:nth-child(2) > li{
    padding-left:10px;
}
#nav > ul > li > ul{
    display:none;
}
#nav > ul > li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
    z-index:5;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    width:200px;
}
#nav > ul > li:hover > ul > li{
    background: #fff;
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    line-height:16px;
    font-weight:normal;
background:red;
z-index:10;
position:relative;
}
#nav > ul > li:hover > ul > li > a{
    color:#333;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">category</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">category</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">category</a></li>
        </ul></li>
    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
    <li>Hello,</li>
    <li><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">country</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">cart</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
Some content
</div>
```

Note that I've set a background color to see that works.

Comment: thanks a million you are a hero I knew I was nearly there and just missing something small